# Как получить атрибут объекта, который содержит тег html

Tags: javascript

Есть функция

```
  function copyValueToInput(el, key) {
    if (!el) return;
    if(typeof el === "object"){
        for(var key in el){
            console.log(el[key]);
        }
    }else{
        var o = document.querySelector('[data-key="' + key + '"]');
        o && (o.value = el.value);
    }
    submitForm();
}
```

Есть два варианта вызова функции, по клику конкретного элемента:

```
<input class="pickpoint_input -inited" type="radio" name="DELIVERY_STORE" id="DELIVERY_STORE_1" value="Москва, ул. Донгузская 19" data-point="93a4eb39" onclick="copyValueToInput(this, 'DELIVERY_STORE');">
<input class="pickpoint_input -inited" type="radio" name="DELIVERY_STORE" id="DELIVERY_STORE_2" value="Москва, ул. Терешковой 32" data-point="93a4eb59" onclick="copyValueToInput(this, 'DELIVERY_STORE');">
<input class="pickpoint_input -inited" type="radio" name="DELIVERY_STORE" id="DELIVERY_STORE_3" value="Москва, ул. Пролетарская 68" data-point="93a4eb75" onclick="copyValueToInput(this, 'DELIVERY_STORE');">
```

Таких элементов столько, сколько магазинов в городе, и получается это условие, которое выполняется в случае `else`, для такого варианта нужно просто кликнуть по магазину.
Но мне нужно, чтобы и по выбору определённого вида доставки, сразу выбирался нужный магазин откуда поедет товар к клиенту, поэтому в чекбокс нужного вида доставки я добавил эту же функцию:

```
<input type="radio" name="ORDER_PROP_DELIVERY" id="ORDER_PROP_DELIVERY_COURIER" onclick="copyValueToInput(document.querySelectorAll('.pickpoint_input'), 'DELIVERY_STORE');">
```

Вот получается по клику на этот чекбокс я передаю объект с элементами класса pickpoint_input, в котором несколько инпутов, по факту, мне нужно из них получить value того, у коготого атрибут `checked="checked"`, либо в функцию передать не объект содержащий все элементы этого класса, а сразу передать тот, у которого `checked="checked"`, но потом как-то получить значение value, как можно это сделать?

Comment: Я мало что понял, посоветую убрать использование js в html, к добру не приведет.
Затем изучи Events (делегирование, target, currentTarget), с новыми знаниями ты сможешь доставать нужные значения из элементов и распоряжаться их атрибутами как душеньке угодно.
А то что ты написал, я, к сожалению, посоветую сжечь...

Comment: Благодарю за совет) в этой ситуации приходится работать с тем, что есть.. чтоб не писать новую функцию, решил слегка расширить имеющуюся, а в целом, абсолютно согласен, такое надо сжегать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получил вот таким образом:

```
  function copyValueToInput(el, key) {
    console.log(el, key);
    if (!el) return;
    if(typeof el === "object"){
        for(var key in el){
            let x = el[key];
            if(x.checked === true){
                console.log(x.value);
            }
        }
    }else{
        var o = document.querySelector('[data-key="' + key + '"]');
        o && (o.value = el.value);
    }
    submitForm();
  }
```